# HDFS - insert new file trigger

Tags: json, hadoop, event-handling, hdfs

Is there such thing as an event, hook or trigger that gets fired when a new file or file version gets added to HDFS? I'm working on a system where we would like to write JSON files to HDFS. The clients writing to the HDFS should be ignorant of the fact that a trigger gets fired that does downstream work with the JSON file.

Please feel free to tweak my question if the language I'm using doesn't fit the correct Hadoop terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) for this. Check the [input events](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.1.4._Input_Events).

Comment: So is Oozie sort of pooling in the background under the covers?

Comment: Oozie is more like crontab. But it allows to setup input events. Check the links in my answer.